# Choosing shoes probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are n pairs of shoes. Find the prob. that among n randomly chosen shoes there is not a pair of matched ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens when we choose one from each pair. The probability is:

$$\frac{\binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{1}\cdots\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{2n}{n}}$$

where the numerator is product of $n$ terms. It simplifies to:

$$\frac{2^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}$$